# Find latest versions of multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: files

I am writing an application and one of the prerequisites is to be able to look at multiple directories and find the latest version of each file.

I've had success with `ls` and `find` in order to get the latest files, but not the latest version of EACH file if those same files are located in multiple directories. One of the caveats is that I will not necessarily know what the files are called, but will know the names of the directories.

**Example:** DIR1, DIR2, and DIR3 each contain a version of FileA and FileB. I need the latest versions of FileA and FileB contained in all three (or more) directories.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look at core utils info pages of find: 'info find'. You will see examples of find utility for queries based on time stamp.

Comment: Supppose you need to compare `DIR1/FileA` with `DIR2/FileA`  : if you changed contains of newer file, and newer file has been changed afer old file you can `find` or `stat command`.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. I'm not sure I understand you, Mohsen.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with your choice of tools:

- `ls -t` is a good way to sort files ordered by time so you can pick off the latest
- `find` is the right tool to find files matching some pattern in directories and subdirectories

The tricky part of course is that you need some kind of grouping by filename,
and pick the latest file in each group.
Because of this requirement,
I think you need a loop,
where you iterate over each target filename to find its latest version.

Assuming the files are in `$dir1`, `$dir2` or `$dir3`,
you could write a function to find the latest version of some pattern like this:

```
find_latest() {
    pattern=$1
    ls -t "$dir1/$pattern" "$dir2/$pattern" "$dir3/$pattern" | head -n 1
}
```

Then let's say if you have the patterns `access.log`, `error.log`, `x*`,
then you can loop over them like this, for example:

```
for pattern in access.log error.log 'x*'; do
    latest=$(find_latest 'a*')
    echo $latest
done
```

If the above assumption is not true,
and the files can be in subdirectories of `$dir1`, `$dir2` or `$dir3`,
then you need to use `find`, it gets a bit more complex:

```
find_latest() {
    pattern=$1
    find "$dir1" "$dir2" "$dir3" -name "$pattern" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t | head -n 1
}
```

There's a small caveat: if a path contains newline characters,
this function won't work well because the `head -n 1` step will chop off the part of the path after the newline. I cross my fingers that you don't have such paths ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `pax`:

```
pax -wrtvZs"|.*/||p" ./DIR[123] "$PWD"
```

So I'll try to break it down by argument:

- `-wr` - these are `w`rite and `r`ead, and together they mean `pax` should copy files rather than archiving. You can forego the copy as well and just create hardlinks instead with `-l`.
- `-t` - this resets all file access times to the state they had before `pax` read them to check their metadata.
- `-v` - works verbosely.
- `-Z` - does not compare the mod times of source files until after all possible name substitutions have completed.

  - It is this *(and the next thing)* that make this so easy. Without this - and likely the problem you'll have elsewhere - is that `DIR1/FILEA` and `DIR2/FILEA` are different files even if they share a basename. And so they're never compared without this and...
- `-s` - substitute and replace portions of a filename with a standard `sed` regexp.

  - Here I just reduce all portions of every file to their basenames, and so `-Z` applies to *all* `FILEA`s and only the newest is copied into `"$PWD"`.

I used the following test to verify all of this:

```
for d in DIR3 DIR1 DIR2
do  cd ~; mkdir -p "$d"; cd "$d"
    sleep 90; touch FILEB FILEA
done; cd ~
```

...which gets the test set. Here are the resulting mod times:

```
ls -l ./DIR[123]/FILE[AB]                                
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:28 ./DIR1/FILEA
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:28 ./DIR1/FILEB
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:29 ./DIR2/FILEA
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:29 ./DIR2/FILEB
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:26 ./DIR3/FILEA
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:26 ./DIR3/FILEB
```

And, so, when I run:

```
pax -wrtvZs"|.*/||p" ./DIR[123] "$PWD"
ls -l ./FILE[AB]
```

...the output is...

```
./DIR1/FILEA >> FILEA
/home/mikeserv/FILEA
./DIR1/FILEB >> FILEB
/home/mikeserv/FILEB
./DIR2/FILEA >> FILEA
/home/mikeserv/FILEA
./DIR2/FILEB >> FILEB
/home/mikeserv/FILEB
./DIR3/FILEA >> FILEA
./DIR3/FILEB >> FILEB

-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:29 ./FILEA
-rw-r--r-- 1 mikeserv mikeserv 0 Dec 20 03:29 ./FILEB
```

You can see it happen. When `-s|||p` changes a filename the `p` modifier prints a message to `stderr`. So we see the `DIR1` files get evaluated first - and copied into `$PWD`, and next the `DIR2` files get the same treatment - but the `DIR3` files are not copied because `$PWD/FILE[AB]` are newer than them now.